# @Qualifier won't work for me to resolve the beans ambguity problems

Tags: java, spring

I am using Spring 4 with Java 8. I am using `@Qualifier` to resolve the ambiguity problem in Spring beans but when I tried to run the application it will showing me error having same ambiguity problem.

**Car.Java**

```
package beans;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;

public class Car {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("e1")
    private Engine engine;

    public void printData() {

        System.out.println("Car Model Year "+engine.getModelyear());
    }
}
```

**Engine.java**

```
package beans;

public class Engine {
    private String modelyear;

    public String getModelyear() {
        return modelyear;
    }

    public void setModelyear(String modelyear) {
        this.modelyear = modelyear;
    }
}
```

**Spring.xml**

```xml
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd" >
   <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"></bean>
   <bean id="e1" class="beans.Engine">
   <property name="modelyear" value="2017"/>
   </bean>
   <bean id="e2" class="beans.Engine">
   <property name="modelyear" value="2018"/>
   </bean>
    <bean id="c" class="beans.Car">

   </bean>

</beans>
```

My Test class is:

```
package test;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

import beans.Car;

public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ap=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("resources/spring.xml");
        Car c=(Car) ap.getBean("c");
        c.printData();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `primary="true"` to the `e1` declaration

```
<bean id="e1" class="beans.Engine" primary="true">
```

Comment: Thanks Sir it work for me can you tell me what does primary="true" mean

Comment: If there are more than one bean of the same class one of them should be primary. I don't know details why. I just got the same problem and solved it by adding the primary mark. For spring it indicates which one should be used if no qualifier is specified

Comment: Indicates that a bean should be given preference when multiple candidates are qualified to autowire a single-valued dependency.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing xml and non-xml configuration. In order to enable autowire, you need to add

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
    <context:annotation-config />
```

to your xml file.

Or you can set the bean manually in xml

```
<bean id="c" class="beans.Car">
    <property name="engine" ref="e1"/>
</bean>
```

but then you need to modify your Car class:

```
private Engine engine;

public void setEngine(Engine engine) {
    this.engine = engine;
}
```

Comment: Sir i am using Annotation and in this there is no need to constructor or setters my question is already solved by @Sangam Belose thanks for your valuable comments.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your problem is the following:
You have defined AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor in your spring xml to process @Autowired annotations but you don't have any post bean processor for your @Qualifier annotation.That is why your @qualifier is ignored.Hence bean ambiguity.

Just add

```
<context:annotation-config/>
```

and remove

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"></bean>
```

since it won't be needed anymore.

Comment: Thanks your answer working for me as well as this is also  work for me i used <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"></bean>                                                           
    <bean id="e1" class="beans.Engine" primary="true"> as well as this is also working for me i just add primary="true" can you plz explain what is deference in both actually i beginer in spring;

Comment: primary="true" is used if you have multiple instances of same bean and you are not using _Qualifier_ anotation.In this case, if you mark **e1**  as primary and if you want to use **e2**,you simply can not do it because e1 will be automatically selected. Just try it out. Put @Qualifier("e2") and you will be still getting "Car Model Year 2017" as output.So using Qualifier(as you already do) and adding an annotation processor (like I have pointed out) will resolve your issue definitely.